# Does AWS offer inter-region / cross region VPC Peering?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

**AWS inter-region / cross region VPC Peering**

We have been using VPC peering for connecting two VPCs within a region. It works great and eliminates the need for a VPN. As we expand to other regions, we use VPNs to connect the VPCs across regions. VPN scaling and HA are two big issues and the connectivity is not robust. Is it possible to create VPC peering between two regions in AWS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AWS announced on [Nov 29, 2017, that AWS started supporting inter-region VPC peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/) and on [Feb 20, 2018 added 9 additional regions](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/inter-region-vpc-peering-is-now-available-in-nine-additional-aws-regions/).

Amazon EC2 now allows peering relationships to be established between Virtual Private Clouds (VPCs) across different AWS regions. Inter-Region VPC Peering allows VPC resources like:

- EC2 instances
- RDS databases
- Lambda functions

**running in different AWS regions to communicate with each other** using private IP addresses, without requiring gateways, VPN connections or separate network appliances. As of Feb 20, 2018, inter-region VPC peering is available in:

- us-east-1 (N. Virginia) (added Nov 29, 2017)
- us-east-2 (Ohio) (added Nov 29, 2017)
- us-west-1 (Northern California) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- us-west-2 (Oregon) (added Nov 29, 2017)
- ap-south-1 (Mumbai) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- ap-southeast-1 (Singapore) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- ap-southeast-2 (Sydney) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- ap-northeast-1 (Tokyo) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- ca-central-1 (Central) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- eu-west-1 (Ireland) (added Nov 29, 2017)
- eu-west-2 (London) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- eu-west-3 EU (Paris) (added Feb 20, 2018)
- sa-east-1 (São Paulo) (added Feb 20, 2018)

For more information: [Announcing Support for Inter-Region VPC Peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/)

- Horizontally scaled
- Highly available
- Encrypts inter-region traffic
- No single point of failure or bandwidth bottleneck
- Traffic always stays on the global AWS backbone and never traverses the public internet
- Reduces threat vectors, such as common exploits and DDoS attacks

Comment: Any idea when this is coming to other regions (such as EU's Frankfurt) ?

Comment: @tutuDajuju AWS says `soon`. Don't know how soon.

Comment: Any performance guarantee for data transfer over inter-region VPC peering?

Comment: @chapter09 See my update. SLA for data transfer is far greater than what you can achieve with a VPN. The traffic stays on AWS backbone and never traverses the public subnet along with HA means it 100% reliable.

Comment: @helloV Thanks for your update. I can imagine the advantages of data transfer over AWS owned links rather than public links. I am also wondering whether there is quantified performance description about the AWS backbone network.

Comment: Worth noting that as of 2018-04-10, AWS just confirmed to me that CloudFormation doesn't support creating inter-region peering. There's apparently a feature request open for this but no ETA.